# How to make the server load php from another directory?

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have a dedicated server and I'm facing a strange issue. I found there 2 php installations and only one must be used and is correct, which is version 5.2.6, but currently, I see on phpinfo that the php.ini is being loaded isn't the right configuration. The php.ini which I need the server use is located in /opt/php-5.2.6/config/php.ini and the current in use is located in /etc/php.ini. How to turn on the php located in /opt/php-5.2.6/ ? I don't know what happened, maybe after I tried to install the xCache extension, but didn't work and in some way that installation of xCache changed where the php is loaded from.

How to make loading the php which I have in directory /opt/php-5.2.6/ ?

Thanks.

Comment: The location of /opt/... looks pretty suspicious, that is not a clean package installed but something installed "wild" by ignoring the package management. That is something one should _never_ do on a modern Linux system. As to which php installation is used: this is configured in the http server configuration. And another side note: php-5.2 is outdated and depreciated.

Comment: Agree to the above. Sorry for not being able to help you much, but you should *not* install packages outside of the package manager (yum on CentOS) unless absolutely required... with EPEL repos available, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your apache to point to another `php.ini` using `.htaccess` file.